# TFS 2018 New Repository Error - Object reference not set to an instance of an objec

Tags: tfs, repository

All of a sudden, when I create a new repo from the dashboard of TFS 2018, I get an error in red located beneath the Repository Name (text field) which says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Trying to troubleshoot this is troublesome. There is nothing in the logs. Drive space is fine. The only thing we have done as of late is detached/reattach the database using the TFS 2018 Admin Console to test copy the database to another server. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Op finally bypass the issue by using below workaround: **Installed TFS Update 3** and everything now works as normal.

---

According to your description, `All of a sudden, when I create a new repo...` Sounds like it worked properly before.

If so, this kind of error may related to TFS or web cache. First test if it works in other project and project collection to check whether it's related to this specific project collection.

Besides, you could give a try with below methods to narrow down the issue:

- Try to clear the cache on this client computer: Close any open
  instances of Visual Studio > Browse to the following folder:
  `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\8.0\Cache.` > Delete the contents of the Cache directory, including all
  subfolders.
- Clear IE/Chrome browser cache, run it with private mode and try
  again.
- Since you have ever detached/reattach the database, try to  restart
  TFS background job agent service which may do the trick.

Comment: @Matthew Well, are you able to create repo using another method such as through CLI? Detail steps please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-cmdline?view=azure-devops

Comment: Besides, do you have any other project collection? Since a database is just a scope of a collection. If you are able to do this in other project collection. Then there maybe something wrong during the operation of detach/reattach the database. You could try to restore your database with an early back-up, which may do the trick.

Comment: Thank you Patrick for your response. This is interesting. Per your suggestions, I created a new Project under the same Default Collection and it successfully created the initial Git Repo. Additionally, I was able to successfully create another repo in the same project. Hoping this fixed something, I went back to my initial project but still could not create a new repo. So it appears my existing project have this issue, but not newly created projects Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Matthew If so, you may need to submit a support ticket at Microsoft.  This is almost impossible to help debug using the information supplied and likely needs specific scripts to get you out of the pickle that only Microsoft Support or the Product team can provide. Create an on-premises incident in this site: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/devops/  If that initial project do not contain any import information or history. You could keep working on that new created project and move source code, clone work item there as a workaround. Hope it helps.

Comment: I just wanted to follow up on how we got around this. We were in the middle of moving our instance to another server anyways so we took a detached a copy of our current instance and reattached to a new instance and everything now works as normal. The only difference between these servers is a minor patch from tfs 2018 patch 2 to tfs 2018 patch 3. My guess is the patch fixed it. Thanks for your help @Patrick.